# C# String "pattern" in variable

Tags: c#, string

how do I put string "pattern" to a variable.

To clearify what I want:

```
string word = "George";
string pattern1 = $"I met person {word}";
string pattern2 = $"I love {word}";

Console.WriteLine(pattern1);
Console.WriteLine(pattern2);

word = "Jimmy";

Console.WriteLine(pattern1);
Console.WriteLine(pattern2);
```

If the "pattern" system worked as I want, I would get this output:

```
I met person George.
I love George.
I met person Jimmy.
I love Jimmy.
```

You get what I want  I don't want to execute the $"..." string I want to save it as "pattern" (I didn't find better word for it) and then execute it when I want (etc with changed variables).

Comment: You cannot change an existing string like that, you always have to create a new one. You could instead safe the "patterns" as strings suitable for `string.Format` and use that to create the strings with the new `word`

Comment: Example using `string.Format` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/BHNGwp

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [the overload of `Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) that takes a [composite formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) and arguments for the string. (Note the lack of $ in front of the pattern strings - we are not performing the interpolation there, but deferring it to be done as part of the `Console.WriteLine` call.)

```csharp
string word = "George";
string pattern1 = "I met person {0}";
string pattern2 = "I love {0}";

Console.WriteLine(pattern1, word);
Console.WriteLine(pattern2, word);

word = "Jimmy";

Console.WriteLine(pattern1, word);
Console.WriteLine(pattern2, word);
```

If you want to store the string after the substitution instead of writing directly to the console, use [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1):

Just make it into a method:

```
private static string pattern1(string word) => $"I met person {word}";
```

Inside your original method, call the new method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(pattern1(word));
```